# a4j commandLink not working with in a4j repeat

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Here is my code :

```
   <a4j:repeat ......>
   <rich:datatable>
   <rich:column>
       <a4j:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{poReceiptBean.testMethod()}" 
        actionListener="#{poReceiptBean.addRowListener}" oncomplete="#
         {rich:component('editReceiptModal')}.show();"></a4j:commandLink>
   </rich:column>
   </rich:datatable>
   </a4j:repeat>
```

Bean :

```
    public void addRowListener(ActionEvent event){
       addInventoryRow = true;
    }
    public void testMethod() {
       System.out.println("hi");
    }
```

both action and actionListener are not invoking bean methods. how to resolve this issue? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which JSF (especially EL) version is used? Check if syntax `testMethod()` is supported in this version. Try to remove oncomplete, or at least change code that it is correct.

Comment: JSF 2.2 used and i forgot to mention that rich datatable is inside a4j repeat.is that causes issue?

Comment: yes buttons inside the a4j repeat is not working, any idea to deal with this?